# spring Autowired Environment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties, spring-security, autowired

I am trying to just grab a simple value out of a properties file. It works in my SpringMVC class but not in my `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`  class.

in the spring-servlet.xml I have defined:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/TcatServer6/myapp/properties/myapp/myapp.properties" />
```

In the code I have:

```
@Value("${anotherapp_url}")
private String anotherAppURL;

@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

In my Spring MVC Controllers, these work just fine. In my spring security login handler, which is a class that extends `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, these both return `null`. Here's my spring-security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="adsh" class="com.cs.mytime.agentdesktop.security.ADAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/agent/**" access="ROLE_AGENT" />
    <form-login
        login-page="/r/views/login.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/r/views/loginfailed.html"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="adsh"
    />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

I have read through a ton of stuff on the internet yet this is always null and can't seem to get it to work. It makes no sense.

Comment: How is `spring-security.xml` being bootstraped? Is it being included in some other file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeanFactory(Post)Processor`s only operate on the context that they are defined in.

The `<context:property-placeholder .. />` defined in the `spring-servlet.xml` does nothing for beans in the `spring-security.xml`. As the first is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` whereas the second is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

You have to declare it twice I'm afraid.